# Rally API Fetch All Features under specific Epic

Tags: api, rally

Hi I cannot find this anywhere and it seems so easy.
I am trying to get All the Features under specific Epic with Alteryx.

I am using this to get them all, but I want to make more precise.

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/portfolioitem/feature?pagesize=2000

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?workspace=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/....
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Got another solution but it is still not perfect:

First I am getting SubEpics

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/portfolioitem/subepic?pagesize=2000&&start=1&query=(Parent.FormattedID = E101)
```

And then Features:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/portfolioitem/feature?pagesize=2000&query=(((Parent.FormattedID = SE104) OR (Parent.FormattedID = SE101)) OR ((Parent.FormattedID = 102) OR (Parent.FormattedID = 103)))
```

Answer (score 0):

OK! Correct answer for Feature is :) Got it with help from SAGI GABAY from CA:

> https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/portfolioitem/feature?pagesize=2000&&start=1&query=(Parent.Parent.FormattedID
>   = E101)

I have also asked about the User Stories level and going this way (Parent.Parent.Parent.FormattedID) doesn't work anymore but you can do this:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?pagesize=2000&&start=1&query=(Feature.Parent.FormattedID = SE101)